# Redirecionar para uma nova rota em react JS

Tags: javascript, react

Pretendo que após o click do botão ocorra um redirecionamento para uma nova rota, fiz esse código mais não funciona podem me ajudar?

````
import Dashboard from './login/Dashboard';
import Home from './login/Home';
import NoMatch from './login/NoMatch';
import Login from './login/Login';
import React, {useState, useContext} from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Routes, useNavigate ,Router, Link} from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
<BrowserRouter>
  <Router>
    <Route path="/home" element={<Home/>}/>
    <Route exact  path="/perfil" element={<Dashboard/>}/>
    <Route  path="*" element={<NoMatch/> } />
</Router>
</BrowserRouter>
    
  );
}
export default App;

import React, {useState, useContext} from 'react';
import {Form, FormControl, Button} from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Link, Route, Routes, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import './login.css';
  export default function Login(){
    const navigate = useNavigate();
  
    function checkUserCredentials(){
        return(
            navigate('/perfil')
        )
    }
   
    return(
        <div className="container">
            <br/>
            <div className="row">  
                    <div className="col-md-6 login-panel">
                        <div className="message"></div>
                        <br/>
                        <h3 className="texto_h3">Insira as suas credencias de acesso</h3>
                        <hr/>
                            <div className='col-md-8'>
                                <Button onClick={checkUserCredentials}>Redirect</Button>
                            </div>
                        
                    </div>  
                     <div className='col-md-6'>
                     
                    </div>   
            </div>
       
           
     
        </div>
       
    )
}
```
````

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Estava com um erro parecido ao usar o React Router v6, pois estava acostumado com a versão anterior. Para o meu código a solução foi retirar o `exact` das rotas, pois na versão nova isso não é mais necessário, todas as rotas já são do tipo exact.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Se for só redirecionamento para rota `/perfil` (sem passagem de dados), é só usar o `useHistory` do `React Router Dom`.

```
import { /*...*/, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function Login(){
   const history = useHistory();

   function checkUserCredentials(){
     history.push("/perfil");
   }
   
   return (
     //...
      <Button onClick={checkUserCredentials}>Redirect</Button>
     //...
   )
}
```

Ou você pode usar o `Link` do `React Router Dom`, é só substituir a `tag` html do botão pelo componente `Link`.

```
export default function Login(){
   return (
     //...
       <Link to="/perfil">Redirect</Link>
     //...
   )
}
```